# aggregation with conditionals?

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-schema

I'm trying to aggregate depending on the conditional if player_id (Gary)
has greater, equal, or less score then player_id("other")

my schema has

```
players(player_id, name) 

matches(match_id, home_team(player_id), away_team(player_id) )

outcome(outcome_id, match_id, home_score:integer, away_score:integer
```

Output from:

```
select m.match_id, p.name AS home_team, p1.name AS away_team, o.home_score, o.away_score
from players p
inner join matches m on (p.player_id = m.home_team)
inner join players p1 on (p1.player_id = m.away_team)
inner join outcomes o on (m.match_id = o.match_id);

 match_id | player_id | player_id | home_score | away_score 
----------+-----------+-----------+------------+------------
        1 | 1         | 2         |          1 |          2
        2 | 2         | 1         |          1 |          3
        3 | 3         | 1         |          3 |          2
```

**Wanted output:**

```
 player_id   | Wins | Draws | Losses
-------------+------+-------+--------
  1          |    1 |    0  |    2
  2    ...   | ...  |    .. |    ...
```

My schema are open for alteration.

EDIT(sqlfiddle): http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b6c8/1

Comment: ah sorry for the ambiguousness, it doesent matter! the focus is more on the getting number of wins losses and draws for each player @Filipe Silva

Comment: Can you add a [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) with your original tables sample data?

Comment: Will do! @FilipeSilva

Comment: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b6c8/1 @FilipeSilva

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `UNION ALL` to get every `outcome` twice, once for `home` and once for `away` player. The second time `home_score`/`away_score` should be switched, to get correct sums for `away` player.

```
select
  d.player_id,
  d.name, 
  sum(d.home_score > d.away_score) as wins,
  sum(d.home_score = d.away_score) as draws,
  sum(d.home_score < d.away_score) as loses
from (
    select p.player_id, p.name, o.home_score, o.away_score
    from players p
    join matches m on p.player_id = m.home_team
    join outcomes o on o.match_id = m.match_id
  union all
    select p.player_id, p.name, o.away_score as home_score, o.home_score as away_score
    from players p
    join matches m on p.player_id = m.away_team
    join outcomes o on o.match_id = m.match_id) d
group by d.player_id, d.name
```

Returns:

```
PLAYER_ID   NAME    WINS    DRAWS   LOSES
1           Gary    1       0       2
2           Tom     1       0       1
3           Brad    1       0       0
```

sqlFiddle demo: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b6c8/21

Comment: Thanks alot! This was soo much help and got the expected result,although I don't know if my schema is correctly setup for answaring this kind of queries! @MarcinJuraszek

Answer (score 1):

For a solution without a subquery and unions: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7b6c8/31

```
SELECT
    p.player_id,
    COALESCE(SUM(o1.home_score > o1.away_score or o2.home_score < o2.away_score), 0) wins,
    COALESCE(SUM(o1.home_score = o1.away_score or o2.home_score = o2.away_score), 0) draws,
    COALESCE(SUM(o1.home_score < o1.away_score or o2.home_score > o2.away_score), 0) losses
FROM players p
LEFT JOIN matches m1 ON (p.player_id = m1.home_team)
LEFT JOIN players p1 ON (p1.player_id = m1.away_team)
LEFT JOIN outcomes o1 ON (m1.match_id = o1.match_id)
LEFT JOIN matches m2 ON (p.player_id = m2.away_team)
LEFT JOIN players p2 ON (p2.player_id = m2.home_team)
LEFT JOIN outcomes o2 ON (m2.match_id = o2.match_id)

GROUP BY p.player_id
```

Results:

```
PLAYER_ID   WINS    DRAWS   LOSSES
1   1   0   2
2   1   0   1
3   1   0   0
4   0   0   0
5   0   0   0
```

Comment: This wont return the result as expected i'm afraid, it should be as Marcin's answare @Wolph

Comment: Indeed, I forgot about the reverse relation :) I've added a modified version. I'm personally not a fan of the union all approach

Comment: ah nice!, thank you for the solution I learnt alot from both examples!
I would like to put your answare as solution aswell but marcin solved it "quicker", in production I think I will go with yours though @Wolph